# When $\cos x$ is transcendental?

Tags: trigonometry, algebraic-number-theory, real-numbers, transcendental-numbers

About the transcendence of trigonometric functions I know that:

1) if $x$ is an algebraic number $\ne 0$ than $\cos x$ is transcendental.

2) if $p=\dfrac{m}{2^n}$ with $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ than $\cos (p\pi)$ is a constructible number (using bisection formula).

After the comments and the answer it's also proved that:

3) For any rational number $q$,  $\cos (q\pi)$ is algebraic ? (since $e^{iq \pi}$ is a root of unity, hence algebraic)

So the open questions are:

> 4) if $a$ is an algebraic number than $\cos (a \pi)$ is algebraic or
>   transcendental?
>
> 5) there exists a transcendental number $\alpha$ such that $\alpha \ne
>  r \pi , \forall r \in \mathbb{Q}$ and if $p=\dfrac{m}{2^n}$ with $m,n
> > \in \mathbb{Z}$ than $\cos (p\alpha)$ is a constructible number?

Someone know if there is some answer to this related questions?

Comment: Part 3 is easy. If $q$ is rational, then $z=e^{\pi i q}$ is a root of unity, hence algebraic. You get the cosine as $\dfrac12(z+\dfrac1z)$ as a sum of two algebraic numbers.

Comment: There is, of course, an exception to 1), namely, $x=0$.

Comment: There are many constructible numbers (between $-1$ and $1$) that are not of the form $\cos(r\pi)$ with $r$ rational. Choose one such. It will be $\cos \alpha$ for some $\alpha$. Then $\cos p\alpha$ will be constructible for $p=m/2^n$.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines as Gerry, but I got stuck in justifying why, say, $\alpha=\arccos(1/\sqrt7)$ would be transcendental. It does follow immediately from item 1, so ... :-) Only the problem of proving that it isn't a rational multiple of $\pi$ remains. But that may be a tractable one.

Comment: In place of $1/\sqrt7$ above one should use a constructible algebraic number $u$ with the property that it itself has absolute value $|u|=1$, but it has conjugates not on the unit circle. Then $u$ won't be a root of unity, and we can use $\alpha=\arccos (\mathrm{Re}\, u)$.

Comment: @Jyrki: I don't understand how can be $|u|=1$ and his conjugate not in the unit circle.

Comment: Algebraic conjugates = zeros of the same polynomial with rational coefficients. For example let $u$ be one of the complex numbers on the unit circle such that its real part is $\sqrt3-\sqrt2$. One of its conjugates (probably, I didn't check everything) has real part $\sqrt3+\sqrt2$, and hence cannot be on the unit circle.

Answer (score 4):

(1) to show that $\cos(\frac {m}{n} \pi)$ is algebraic it is enough to show that 
$\cos(\frac{1}{n} 2\pi)$ is algebraic. So it comes down to showing that the real part of an $n$-th root of unity is algebraic.

(3) there is a transcendental  $a$ not equal to any rational multiple of $\pi$. Just take square root of $(\pi -1)$, lest $\pi$ would be algebraic.

Comment: Your statement (1) answers my question 3), but your (3) does not fit my question 5). And you have some idea about my 4)?

Answer (score 1):

(4) $\cos(a\pi)=\frac{e^{ia\pi}+e^{-ia\pi}}{2}$ so $\cos(a\pi)$ is algebraic iff $e^{ia\pi}$ is algebraic.

Since $e^{ia\pi} = (e^{i\pi})^a$ and $e^{i\pi}=-1$ is algebraic, the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) implies that $\cos(a\pi)$ is transcendental if $a$ is algebraic but not rational.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we need to remember the general formula for the cosine of an arbitrary complex number.

Let $H$ be the measure of a half-circle ($H$ depends on the unit you use for angle measurement), $e$ be the base of the natural logarithm, and let $i^2=-1$.

Then

$$ cos(x)=\frac{e^{\frac{ix}{H}}+e^{\frac{-ix}{H}}}{2}=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{x}{H}}+(-1)^{\frac {-x}{H}}}{2}$$

$-1$ is, of course, an algebraic number. So if $\frac{x}{H}$ is algebraic *and* irrational, then $cos(x)$ is transcendental.

Some implications

If the unit used is such that $H$ is rational, $cos(x)$ is transcendental for all irrational algebraic $x$, and algebraic for all rational $x$. If $x$ is irrational, $H$ is rational, and $cos(x)$ is algebraic, $x$ must be transcendental, per Gelfond-Schneider theorem.

When radians are used, $H$=. Per Lindemann-Weierstrauss theorem, $cos(x)$ would be transcendental for all nonzero algebraic $x$ radians. This is because the formula simplifies to $\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$. If a rational multiple of  radians is used, then $cos(x)$ is algebraic.