# Are the acute angle of a 3-4-5 right triangle transcendental

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

Define a transcendental angle as a transcendental multiple of a right angle. Are the acute angles of the 3-4-5 right triangle transcendental?

Answer (score 0):

$cos(x)=3/4$

The cosine of a rational multiple of a right angle is algebraic.

Per Gelfond-Schneider theorem, the cosine of an irrational, algebraic multiple of a right angle is transcendental.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4857678

So $x$ must be a rational or transcendental multiple of a right angle. Per Niven's Theorem, published in Irrational Numbers by Ivan Niven, $x$ can not be a rational multiple of a right angle. So $x$ must be a transcendental multiple of a right angle.